# ¿Porque no funciona Top:10% en la Caja_Azul, como sí lo hace Right:10%?

Tags: css

¿Porque no funciona Top:10% en la Caja_Azul, como sí lo hace Right:10% ? ¿Cuáles son las alternativas para que Top esté al 10%?

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="Contenedor">
        <div id="Caja_Naranja"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/ddvh9m/600x400_Naranja.jpg" style="width: 100%"></div>
        <div id="Caja_Azul"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/gUoPN6/100x60_Azul.jpg"></div>
    </div>

</body>

<style>

   * {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

   #Contenedor {
        position: relative;
        width: 75%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

   #Caja_Naranja {
        position: absolute;
        width:100%;
    }

   #Caja_Azul {
        position: absolute;
        right: 10%;
        top: 10%;
    }

</style>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto pasa por aplicar porcentaje la cual es una unidad de medida relativa al bloque contenedor.

Si aplicas `px` (unidad relativa respecto de la pantalla del usuario) no pasaría esto, ver ejemplo:

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#Contenedor {
    position: relative;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#Caja_Naranja {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
}

#Caja_Azul {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10%;
    top: 10px; /* ahora está en px */
}
```

```html
<div id="Contenedor">
    <div id="Caja_Naranja"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/ddvh9m/600x400_Naranja.jpg" style="width: 100%"></div>
    <div id="Caja_Azul"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/gUoPN6/100x60_Azul.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Ahora, para que puedas trabajar con `%` tiene que saber `#Caja_Azul` de donde coger las medidas. El contenedor padre `#Contenedor` no tiene ninguna asignada ni tampoco hereda de ningún elemento la altura que tiene que tener el contenedor.

Así que le damos a los elementos `html y body` una altura por defecto de `100%` (leer sobre: [Misterios alturas en porcentajes](https://escss.blogspot.com.es/2014/07/misterios-alturas-en-porcentajes.html))

Con esto tampoco te funcionaría lo esperado:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#Contenedor {
    position: relative;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#Caja_Naranja {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
}

#Caja_Azul {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10%;
    top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="Contenedor">
    <div id="Caja_Naranja"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/ddvh9m/600x400_Naranja.jpg" style="width: 100%"></div>
    <div id="Caja_Azul"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/gUoPN6/100x60_Azul.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Pero ahora, en el momento que le demos una altura al `#Contenedor` (en este ejemplo un 100%), podemos darle altura al hijo `#Caja_Azul` la altura deseada:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#Contenedor {
    position: relative;
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#Caja_Naranja {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
}

#Caja_Azul {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10%;
    top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="Contenedor">
    <div id="Caja_Naranja"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/ddvh9m/600x400_Naranja.jpg" style="width: 100%"></div>
    <div id="Caja_Azul"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/gUoPN6/100x60_Azul.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Puedes leer más sobre este tema en:

- [librosweb.es - Unidades de medida](http://librosweb.es/referencia/css/unidades_de_medida.html)
- [librosweb.es -Porcentajes](http://librosweb.es/referencia/css/porcentajes.html)

Comment: Que Caja_Azul sea responsive. (al reducir el ancho de la pagina web)

Comment: @peruvice - ¿Responsive como? Tu pregunta era: _¿Porque no funciona Top:10% en la Caja_Azul....?_ Si tienes otra duda te sugiero que elabores otra pregunta con el problema que tienes... saludos